# How can I play Minecraft in fullscreen mode in Linux?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

How can I play Minecraft in fullscreen in Linux? On my system, I only get a windowed mode with a quarter of the screen size and the rest is black.

I am using ArchLinux and the awesome [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) window manager.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Press <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Be aware that currently (= version 1.2_02) I am experiencing an issue with controlling the GUI with the mouse when coming back from full screen. You might want to maximize the game window instead, for the time being.

Comment: That issue is listed as a known bug. Mouse functionality does not work within GUIs until you restart the client.

Answer (score -1):

Press F11.  If you are on a Mac, however, use CMD + F11

Comment: It's generally bad form to post an answer that doesn't add anything to the current, existing answers.  If you see an answer that you could contribute to in some small way (CMD+F11 for example), feel free to edit it!